# How to set up a child theme using pattern lab?

Tags: 8

I have multisite architecture in drupal 8. and I am using pattern lab in my base theme but now I want to access some component from parent theme to child theme. What would be the best way to create child theme using pattern lab? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Drupal answers.

Patternlab does not have opinion about Drupal theme hierarchy. So given you are maintaining the parent child hierarchy as per Drupal theming structure your child theme must be able to inherit all the component templates from parent to child.

While there could be multiple ways you can go ahead with development in future, one way would be to keep creating new components at parent theme & pattern lab. Patternlab can continue using base theme styling to show the components whereas  in Drupal styling(css) would be dynamic via variables which would be decided for what theme you are building.